# Some assets from SWC are not imported in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swc

For almost all of my projects I export visual assets from Flash Pro to SWC to then import them in Flash Builder. Today I stumbled across a really bothersome problem.

Some of my assets are **not** being imported. I've tried clearing my projects multiple times, restarting my Flash Builder IDE, re-exporting my SWC.

Clearly there's a problem when importing it, because when I decompiled my SWC/library.swf, I saw that all of my assets are exported just fine. When I decompile my output SWF I see that instead of some assets there is a red rectangle, and some of them are just invisible.

I don't know what to think and can't figure it out. The only thing that might be a case is the file size of the SWC (approximately 2.5 MB), and there are almost 160 linkages in there.

I wasn't able to find anything on the internet regarding the file size limit or anything like that.

I'm using Flash Pro CC and Flash Builder 4.7 Standard on a Mac OS X 10.8.4

These are the red boxes I'm talking about (there should be other bitmaps instead of them):

[image: SWC Import problem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the bitmap properties you have set for the missing Bitmaps. 
- Photo (JPEG)
- Lossless (PNG/GIF)
If you have JPEG selected this might be the problem

Comment: Wow. Any explanations why this can be a problem? Of course I have some of my images exported with the compression, otherwise output would be gigantic. Anyway I'll try to set it as Lossless and let you know the result. Thanks.

Comment: Man you're a genius! Could you please explain a little further, why this happens? It really fixed my problem, but I can't make all my assets lossless. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: I can't find where I found the solution to this problem anymore but you CAN still use Jpegs as long as you don't specify "use document default" at the compression settings for your image. It seems to be a bug in the new compiler that comes with Flash Builder 4.7 because the same publish settings still work with older versions of FB.

Comment: I didn't have time to try out that, but was thinking of trying it. Thank you very much for your response. It almost drove me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same happened to me with exporting SWC from Adobe Flash CS5.5 and using this SWC in Flash Builder 4.7. In my case some pictures are not being shown in resulting SWF file. The solution is one of the following:

1. Use JPEGs instead of PNGs.
2. Use no compression (lossless PNGs.)
3. Use compression not by default, which may be the same as the default setting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already received the answer way back.